# Fail to Sign/Verify signature in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, signature, public-key

I am trying to use the .Net RSA functions to sign a Hash, but when i try to Sign the hash and then verify the Signed string it turns out false. This can be reproduced by running the `DoTest()` Function.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Crypto
{
    public static class Signing
    {
        public static string Sign(string Hash)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSA.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>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</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>wJjH5cYFiOYIz/9IENUiZ/F6TkE0jq2l8JpXk2dGKvzqlOO93i6pJ2rRUdugLRiqzSOt+yE2Jpxued6gumzqvsy0q5HLTqY1n0eLVOfkn4x8tRvMAVbW185duBkgHLuLAzkJqnAd8CXpkca4M7mvWi4EDpiPoSJjeZt0kSkaRzjOSEp4Q5WZUhN5gRM7mn2VQSawFIJtNxAJLuneEc03D8O41+9KVQ8sS7AIVZdu6ortvBveU8e7HA/CNIutyFcdtgoCu4XUQSlAQQD75qlfSJvPT7rvxUsc53FKAIcQNz28g4Zy8/2K8B7T6SChsalUNcbiDuQcBtzAEBDkDlO8Fw==</P><Q>3UZ35kUnAbj/IY/kSsOsMwWjw0djKnY+Yt22vcN4FImhMyMTKKnpCbX+XFQpK6Gh8Gv4lVjgeDi+fb6AbzDFff2fEGwmVyI4EkRa50KdTQKwCZrxwpljngl3M06vTXzjV1L9IcBXQt3so7HA4YJ4kY8woadgz/41+dij6Nlz4bAn+VA8QIbjR0x9rOR/FxM0cCsTqNYsDUxmyqwPlqWdA73KoAFyjGg12fij3BKZdT3AnGeOZUp4Ukb/Xapaj8E8jIAtl1/p9uVEj6gZqcSkBhj1IE+zJ54iS7u8Ijd8SBcLbfsJ+12FXCT/zFsTJ+UUro+dQYKzUe05WMN5Eowogw==</Q><DP>A1LfqER5lfo6TrSeHsQ+2sJdFPqlGI1Ant1bA401tco1lioz/aCahLagNCRxKDYTxISIHRxend33Ph0scussReysdYWHl6zgogYPDoEN/f7jrBB1vdQs0v6ZuXKdjkFiTcTvOMTEj39n/38JcMMUlp7SrRnO6L36L4ASS+sErBP74119o9TyF2uEnkihr7HZII21XjU+A0RAlFGu5mm/OINtLjTP+JXRcuDv0+JQJLYPEj784D9DKGHRPSzn69wtBBY6I9hUaGd412ZX8owbu9oMgti8CJCaSBg5abbq/bkQBskMNM+8VRaDG7PXdoRwkpkDD7S6Exg+LEjOVrz1Mw==</DP><DQ>2mYMP6Zvep7KiqjIThbVpsJhQYP7V9S/fLuS+7erlLHG/n8XEOKrVV9hAGY9AIiXGoKnJ1lCrMZtFhVqFNURiGpEjmQAb64ho7397xXrxi/p6oEZL9ZP4ZM8KNL36cZjaTRLDf4W4rPCNktisfIh6KFpAZT/1Cr3wXNXTKMcYlyJB+Vuos3AFAZmYLhizDazYibST6mcbz/CkTXEaQ9ra17vWIA1PGo7BLoJmVRuTK63pmf7vvQC0EqtEBjtK8gxaAe3eBo+BeeChTwIoGyq7C3D+7FOhcLp3NAeP7N+InVEXbgSwRwsXadTJrOZs53CjQzIzPkg3rMDEB5XKLxX2w==</DQ><InverseQ>srv0aCRx+dycT8mBMxGemXBal88+lPDd4l1okp1CY0Lv7lL2AojYQvQT3Ks8AuSzLyWuZ8sQl2JD/QsluZSbvWLb/RMW/h64DbM3ei108krbu5EHPWyGDdJSTtDR0XtNouQBCS4D1rc8M2psexexpIr/8uQG93I2h3hAddQ4SSspQs3oV4PMSVwFQLsxTaxVMi+F+Enu2W5a98+MPCQGoZcwatu3gow+2lFFAe2lTcSiEZdJEUbyxWG6sgh1iBv0gypN3Bny06peK1gZLd+IAyjpYyl9JCPZqWXxvcaJUtduR/JGA8NypCs+QBNwse2d4ipJVxhn756EOavOR/GYHg==</InverseQ><D>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</D></RSAKeyValue>");
            byte[] SignedHashValue = RSA.SignHash(HashBytes(Hash),"SHA512");
            return (Convert.ToBase64String(SignedHashValue));
        }

        public static bool Verify(string signature, string Hash)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSA.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>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</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>");
            bool verified = RSA.VerifyData(HashBytes(Hash),"SHA512", Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
            return verified;
        }

        public static byte[] HashBytes(String hex)
        {
            int NumberChars = hex.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            {
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        public static void DoTest()
        {
            string hash = "878AE65A92E86CAC011A570D4C30A7EAEC442B85CE8ECA0C2952B5E3CC0628C2E79D889AD4D5C7C626986D452DD86374B6FFAA7CD8B67665BEF2289A5C70B0A1";
            string signed = Sign(hash);
            bool Verified = Verify(signed, hash);
            Console.WriteLine(Verified);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to crypto.se - Programming questions are meant for stackoverflow, even if it is related to cryptography. We can migrate this there for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] of your code, which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows that the result is `false` even though the signature should be valid. Also include the code which produced the signature or provide the documentation how it was created and in which format it is saved.

Comment: On a side note: Variables should begin in lowercase to avoid confusion with class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter` class, when you try to verify a hash with the `RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData()` method. The signature must come from the `RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData()` method, as stated in the documentation of [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifydata?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> **Remarks**
>
> This method verifies the RSA digital signature produced by the `SignData` method. [...]

Use the `SignData()` method to sign the data and use the `VerifyData()` method to check the signature.